# How to remove multversion packages with chef?

Tags: linux, chef-infra, suse

I would like to remove certain versions of "multiversion" packages (kernel in my case) with chef on SUSE Linux (for now). Afterwards I want to install a new version for the same package.
I could not find a way to do it. 
"package" does not seem to work, and the documentation also only talks about installing specific versions, nor does rpm_package work. 
For example

```
package "kernel-desktop" do
  version "3.12.1-1"
  action :remove
end
```

does not seem do anything

Comment: Package is exactly the thing that should work. Post some code, how did use it and failed?

Comment: No package did not work for me

Comment: What exactly did you try? Post code and chef output.

Comment: How would you do this without Chef?

Comment: What do you wish to do, remove only or purge the package?